# Why can't I have a definiens with type parameters in MMT (using PLF)?

Tags: dependent-type, formal-methods, mmt

I'm trying to define pairs using `ur:?PLF`:

```
theory pairs : ur:?PLF =
    pair :      {a : type} a ⟶ a ⟶ (a ⟶ a ⟶ a) ⟶ a ❙    // okay     ❙
    pair_kind = {a : type} a ⟶ a ⟶ (a ⟶ a ⟶ a) ⟶ a ❙    // not okay ❙
❚
```

The declaration of `pair` type-checks as I would expect.
However, the definition of `pair_kind` does not.

Is this expected behaviour?
I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using PLF, which extends LF with *shallow polymorphism* - shallow meaning that quantification over types is *only* allowed on the outside of types.

In order to make that work, an expression `{a : type} ...` is not allowed to be typed itself, otherwise you could freely quantify over types unrestrictedly.

The way this works in PLF is that expressions of the form `{a : type} ...` are *inhabitable* but - as I mentioned - not *typed*. *Inhabitable* meaning, it is allowed to occur as a "type" of a constant. Since it's not typed, you can't use a constant of that type (like `pair`) in an expression *unless* you provide the type arguments. So `pair` does not have a type, but `pair A` (for some type A) does.

That's why `pair : {a : type} ...` is accepted.

When you do `pair_kind = {a : type} ...`, you provide the expression as a definiens and do not provide a type, which means MMT will try to infer one - and (since this expression is not typed) fail.

If you want `pair_kind` to work, you need to use a stronger type system. For example `?LFHierarchy` in LFX, which has a cumulative universe hierarchy (`U n` for every positive integer n) and defines `type` as `U 0` and `kind` as `U 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! On the technical side: replacing `ur:?PLF` with `http://gl.mathhub.info/MMT/LFX/TypedHierarchy?LFHierarchy` as meta theory made it type-check indeed.

Comment: Is there any rule set of what expressions are inhabitable in (P)LF and LFHierarchy, respectively? I'd be interested in that, I have been facing "inhabitable" errors regularly in the past :-)

Comment: a term t is inhabitable iff either 1. There's an *Inhabitable* rule that declares t to be inhabitable, or 2. t has an inferrable type T and there's a universe rule declaring T to be a universe, or 3. t itself is a universe.

In LF, "type" and "kind" are universes, and that's it.

In PLF, we add a rule tha any term `{x : type} t` is inhabitable iff t is inhabitable.

In LFHierarchy, we declare U(n) to be a universe for each positive integer n, the inferred type of U(n) is U(n+1), and U(n) type checks against U(m) if n < m.

Comment: This is described in detail (among other places) in my dissertation, btw: https://kwarc.info/people/dmueller/pubs/thesis.pdf
(Sections I.4.2.1. ff)